# Update Date Column and Format Date to Same pattern

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have dates in a column of database but the date format is not same. Some are `mm-dd-yyyy` and some are `mm.dd.yy` or other. How do I format it into same type using a query?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What **datatype** is that column?? Dates aren't stored as strings in SQL Server - so they don't have any **format** associated with them - that is, **IF** you use the proper datatypes (`DATE` or `DATETIME`)

Comment: +1 @marc_s - formatting has nothing to do with storage.

Comment: the column is varchar but I have date in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be:

1. Add a column of type `DATE` to your table:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD NewDateColumn DATE
   ```
2. Update your table to convert those `varchar` values to `DATE`:

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.YourTable
   SET NewDateColumn = CAST(YourOldColumn AS DATE)
   WHERE NewDateColumn IS NULL AND ISDATE(YourOldColumn) = 1
   ```
3. Drop that old column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DROP COLUMN YourOldColumn
   ```

From now on - use the new `DATE` column exclusively.

You can format it to any string representation that is [supported in SQL Server using the `CONVERT` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Once you have that `DATE` column, you can output it in whatever string formatting you need:

```
SELECT
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 101) 'US format', 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 102) 'ANSI format', 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 104) 'German format'
```

gives you:

```
US format   ANSI format German format
12/29/2011  2011.12.29  29.12.2011
```